# How to get a tag's description with Stack Exchange API?

Tags: stackexchange-api

How to get a tag's description (excerpt) via the Stack Exchange API?

Comment: Call [`api.stackexchange.com/2.2/tags/php/wikis?site=stackoverflow&filter=!6JEVX4hBMf8fz`](//api.stackexchange.com/2.2/tags/php/wikis?site=stackoverflow&filter=!6JEVX4hBMf8fz) (replace `php` with the tag you want. excerpt is the description, body is the wiki). Play with it in [the API documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/wikis-by-tags).

Comment: I have another question.

I need to have list of tags with 3 fields: 1) tag_name 2) tag_description 3) counter_of_posts.

Since counter_of_posts is a field of tag-object and "tag_description" (excerpt) is a field of tag_wiki - how can I get needed information through 1 query? I know how to do it in SQL - SELECT from 2 TABLES, but here?

Seperate question created - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61055161/stack-exchange-api-how-to-get-information-from-different-objects-in-1-query

Answer (score 0):

> Call [`api.stackexchange.com/2.2/tags/php/wikis?site=stackoverflow&filter=!6JEVX4hBMf8fz`](//api.stackexchange.com/2.2/tags/php/wikis?site=stackoverflow&filter=!6JEVX4hBMf8fz) (replace `php` with the tag you want. excerpt is the description, body is the wiki). Play with it in [the API documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/wikis-by-tags).

Thanks to [double-beep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10607772/double-beep)!