# How to get information from different objects with 1 call?

Tags: stackexchange-api

I need to have list of tags with 3 fields:

1. tag_name
2. tag_description
3. counter_of_posts.

Since `counter_of_posts` is a field of tag-object and tag_description (excerpt) is a field of `tag_wiki`, how can I get needed information with one call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is impossible - you need at least 2 calls (more if you have more than 20 tags). One call to `/tags/{tags}/info?site={site}` to get the tag's name (which is given) and the counter and one to `/tags/{tags}/wikis?site={site}`. Of course, you can apply whatever filters you want and change the sitename and tag names. Here's a JavaScript sample:

```js
(async function() {
  const key = '3loXx7CAr2AvrMaHBj6GxQ(('; // not necessary, but it increases daily API quota from 300 to 10000
  const sitename = 'stackoverflow'; // default, change it to whatever you want
  const tags = 'php;javascript;java;jquery;perl;python'; // semicolon-separated, must be =<20
  const tagApiUrl = 'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/tags/';
  const tagInfoFilter = '!-.G.68pp778y';
  const tagWikisFilter = '!*Ly1)NvM)n91RtK*';

  // First API call: get tag's info
  const callTagInfo = await fetch(`${tagApiUrl}${tags}/info?site=${sitename}&filter=${tagInfoFilter}&key=${key}`);
  const data_counter = await callTagInfo.json();

  // Second API call: get tag's excerpt
  const callTagWikis = await fetch(`${tagApiUrl}${tags}/wikis?site=${sitename}&filter=${tagWikisFilter}&key=${key}`);
  const data_excerpt = await callTagWikis.json();

  for (let i = 0; i < data_counter.items.length; i++) {
    const table = document.querySelector('table');
    const html = `
      <tr>
        <td>${data_counter.items[i].name}</td>
        <td>${data_excerpt.items.find(name => name.tag_name === data_counter.items[i].name).excerpt}</td>
        <td>${data_counter.items[i].count}</td>
      </tr>`;
     table.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
  }
  console.log('API Quota remaining:', data_excerpt.quota_remaining);
})();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@stackoverflow/stacks/dist/css/stacks.min.css">
<table class="s-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Tag Name</th>
      <th>Excerpt</th>
      <th>Number of posts</th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```